# How do I customise the dropdown when my navbar collapses?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navbar on my page where the left hand side contains a bunch of views and the right hand side contains a bunch of actions (eg. create)

On mobile devices, I want the left side to collapse into a dropdown box while the action commands on the right stay the same.

I can get this working but I can't get it looking right. I have some working code here.

http://www.bootply.com/OEYfZVIaGA#

Basically, the problem I have is on the mobile view, when I click on "Toggle view", it turns the entire navbar into a dropdown list and drags the right hand side buttons down as well.

I would like it to act just like a standard dropdown list (http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns-example). I would be happy if it didn't drag the New button down when I opened the dropdown list.

How do I customise the behaviour of the drop down list from a collapsed navbar?

Comment: `navbar-header pull-left` seems to be pushing it down with margin, but I can't seem to get rid of the margin with CSS. Strange.